# allow service to be used with both http and https URL

Tags: wcf, https

Http url is working fine, but if I try the same for https url , I am getting the following exception :

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
>   StoreName 'TrustedPeople', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType
>   'FindByThumbprint', FindValue
>   '67C54590FD5ECDD33901E6440F81B5EE60F9BF40'.

Comment: How did you configured HTTPS, how are you hosting the service. This is so bare question that it cannot be answered at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the SSL certificate and put it on your IIS.

Comment: I already have the certificate , since its working fine with http.

Comment: @NRT: Certificate is not used for HTTP ... unless you configured message security as well.